# How to deal with multiple categories entry for an article website

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a news web application, and each news has a category field, but this category can be one, or many at times. Which means, that a person may enter `politics, world, us` tags for just one news article. Now, the problem I have is how to insert this into a database. If I just enter the tags directly to database, as pure text, then I when I have to echo it, I could use explode() to separate them, like

```
$row['tags] = 'politics, world, us';

foreach(explode($row['tags') as  $tag){
  echo "<a href='{$tag}'> {$tag} </a> ";
}
```

Which would echo the tags, and create a hyperlink for each tag, but the problem I have with this is that, if user wants to just see a news with a specific tag, it becomes problem because there is ~no way I could query all the rows, sort out, explode the tags and just show the news feed like that. It is doable, but very cumbersome. So, I would like to ask how to do this. I am certain it involves, having having maybe another table called `tags` but that is as far as I can go

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to make a many to many relationship in database. This would require additional table containing id's of categories and articles related to each other

Look at this example of multiple users with multiple roles:

[image]

In the same way, you can create a relationship of articles to categories

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) to store the data or, which I suggest, add another table for tags and one which stores relations between articles and tags as mentioned by Maciej.

articles table:

```
id | title | content
```

tags table:

```
id | label
```

articles_tags table:

```
article_id | tag_id
```

Consider adding [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) to the last table, this will make your life easier.